# How to use SIGFPE with signal?

Tags: c++, signals

I just informed myselve about "signals" in C/C++ and played around. But i have a problem to understand the logic of `SIGFPE`.

I wrote a little program which will run into a division by zero, if this happens then the signal should be triggered and the signal handler should be executed. But instead my program just crashes. So what is the purpose of the `SIGFPE` if it does not even work on division by zero?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>

int signal_status = 0;

void my_handler (int param)
{
    signal_status = 1;
    printf ("DIVISION BY ZERO!");
}

int main ()
{

    signal (SIGFPE, my_handler);
    int result = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf ("signaled is %d.\n", signal_status);

        for(int i=10000; i>-1; i--)
        {
            result = 5000 / i;
        }
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most signals are OS specific. For Linux, read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and notice that you are allowed only to use async signal safe functions (there are very few of them) in signal handlers. In particular using `printf` (or `std::cout` and e.g. its `operator <<`) in a signal handler is forbidden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signal SIGFPE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628947/signal-sigfpe-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I commented, most signals are OS specific. For Linux, read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). You forgot a `\n` inside your `printf` (usually, you'll be lucky enough to see something work in your code, but read all my answer). And in principle you should not call `printf` (which is not an async-signal-safe function, you should use directly and only [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) inside) from your signal handler.

What probably is happening is (ignoring the [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) posed by wrongly using `printf` inside the signal handler) is that:

- your `stdout` buffer is never flushed since you forgot a `\n` (you might add a `fflush(NULL);`...) in the `printf` inside `my_handler` in your code
- probably, the SIGFPE handler restarts again the [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) instruction triggering it. (More exactly, after returning from [sigreturn(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigreturn.2.html) your machine is in the same state as it was before `SIGFPE` was delivered, so the same divide-by-zero condition happens, etc...)

It is difficult (but painfully possible, if you accept coding hardware-specific and operating-system specific code) to handle `SIGFPE`; you would use [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) with `SA_SIGINFO` and handle the third argument to the signal handler (which is a `ucontext_t` pointer *indirectly* giving the machine state, including [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register), which you might change inside your handler; in particular you could change your return [program counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) there). You might also consider using [sigsetjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigsetjmp.3.html) inside your signal handler (but it is in theory forbidden, since not async-signal-safe).

<sup>(You certainly need to understand the details of your processor's [instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) architecture and your operating system's [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface); and you probably would need a week of coding work after having mastered these)</sup>

In a portable POSIX way, `SIGFPE` cannot really be handled, as explained in [Blue Moon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33585560/841108)

Probably, the runtime of [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) or of [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/) is handling `SIGFPE` in a machine & operating system specific way to report zero-divides as divide-by-zero exceptions .... (to Java programs for JVM, to Common Lisp programs for SBCL). Alternatively their [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_in_Time) or compiler machinery could generate a test before every division.

BTW, a flag set inside a signal handler should be declared `volatile sig_atomic_t`. See POSIX specification about [`<signal.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html)

As a pragmatical rule of thumb, a POSIX portable and robust signal handler should only set some `volatile sig_atomic_t` and/or perhaps [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) a few bytes to some [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (your process could set up a pipe to itself -as [recommended by Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html)-, with another thread and/or some event loop reading it), but this does not work for *asynchronous* [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29)-generated signals like `SIGFPE`,  `SIGBUS`, `SIGILL`,  and `SIGSEGV`, etc... (which could only be handled by painful computer-specific code).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21204438/841108) to a very related question.

At last, on Linux, signal processing is believed to be not very quick. Even with a lot of machine-specific coding, emulating [GNU Hurd external pagers](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/doc/hurd_5.html#SEC32) by tricky `SIGSEGV` handling (which would `mmap` lazily ....) is believed to be quite slow.

Answer (score 2):

Divide by zero is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So whether you have installed a handler for `SIGFPE` or not is of little significance when your program invokes undefined behaviour.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) says:

> Delivery of the signal shall have no effect on the process. The
>   behavior of a process is undefined after it ignores a SIGFPE, SIGILL,
>   SIGSEGV, or SIGBUS signal that was not generated by kill(),
>   sigqueue(), or raise().

A signal is raised as a result of an event (e.g. sending `SIGINT` by pressing <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>) which can be handled by the process *if* said event non-fatal. `SIGFPE` is an erroneous condition in the program and you can't *handle* that. A similar case would be attempting to handle `SIGSEGV`, which is equivalent to this (undefined behaviour). When your process attempts to access some memory for which it doesn't have access. It would be silly if you could just ignore it and carry on as if nothing happened.

Comment: Ok, but on the website where i found the signal function described, there is following explanation about `SIGFPE` 

"The signal is displayed on a division by 0" (i translated it from german)
But as we can see it makes no sense to use `SIGFPE`.

Comment: @EdwardBlack: you *could* handle `SIGFPE` but you need some difficult, operating system & hardware specific, code. See my answer.