# IEEE 754, division by zero

Tags: ieee-754, divide-by-zero

I know in standard IEEE 754 division by zero is allowed. I want to know how it's represented in binary.

For example, 0.25 in decimal is
`0 01111101 00000000000000000000000`
 in binary. What about 5.0/0.0 or 0.0/0.0 do they have represenation in binary, and are they same?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you divide a finite number by zero you'll get an infinity with the sign of the number you tried to divide. So 5.0/0.0 is +inf but 0.0/0.0 returns something called a QNaN indefinite.

Let’s say we are dividing negative one by zero. Because this results in a pre-computed exception I think the key to understanding what happens is in the “response” verbiage Intel uses in section 4.9.1.2

> The masked response for the divide-by-zero exception is to set the ZE flag and return an infinity signed with the exclusive OR of the sign of the operands.

I hope I’m reading this right. Since the Zero mask bit (found in the control word of the x87 FPU) is a 1, the pre-computed exception flag becomes set once the fpu detects the zero in the operand used for division. Now the processor knows to do something like this:

```
    1 sign of operand 1, our -1.0
xor 0 sign of operand 2, the zero 
----------
    1 response
```

Now with that response bit I know whether I have a positive or negative infinity

```
-inf 1 11111111 00000000000000000000000
-----+-+------+-+---------------------+
     | |      | |                     |
     | +------+ +---------------------+
     |    |               |
     |    v               v
     | exponent        fraction
     |
     v
     sign
```

If I had a positive 1.0 instead and divided by zero:

```
    0 sign of operand 1
xor 0 sign of operand 2
-----------
    0
```

Now I have
`inf 0 11111111 00000000000000000000000`

As long as the numerator is positive and you're dividing by zero you'll get the same positive infinity.
This is what I imagine happening when I run something like this:

```
int main() {
    SetExceptionMask(exAllArithmeticExceptions);    
    float a = -1;
    float b = a / 0.0f;
    printf("%f\n", b);
}
```

The result is -inf which looks like this `1 11111111 00000000000000000000000`

QNaNs ("quiet not a number") are especially helpful for debugging and are generated through a few different ways but 0.0/0.0 will return something that looks like this:

```
qnan 0 11111111 10000000000000000000000
-----+-+------+-+---------------------+
                |                     |
                +---------------------+
                         |
                         v
                      fraction
```

Now software can manipulate the bits in the fraction of a QNaN for any purpose, usually this seems done for diagnostic purposes.
To learn more I recommend watching parts 31(https://youtu.be/SsDoUirLkbY), and 33(https://youtu.be/3ZxXSUPSFaQ) of this Intel Manual reading.

Answer (score 0):

Mark has corrected me that division by zero results in positive or negative infinity in IEEE 754-2208.

In the wikipedia article on the subject, we find the following:

> sign = 0 for positive infinity, 1 for negative infinity.
>
> biased exponent = all 1 bits.
>
> fraction = all 0 bits.

*Source:* [IEEE 754 Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)

I was wrong in thinking it would result in a NaN, upon which I elaborated below.

+Infinity:

```
0 11111111 00000000000000000000000
```

-Infinity:

```
1 11111111 00000000000000000000000
```

---

**INCORRECT ORIGINAL RESPONSE BELOW**

*May still be of tangential interest, so leaving it in.*

---

This results in, from my understanding, a `NaN`, pr **not a number*.

The wikipedia page on Nan has an encoding section from which the following quote arrives.

> In IEEE 754 standard-conforming floating-point storage formats, NaNs are identified by specific, pre-defined bit patterns unique to NaNs. **The sign bit does not matter.** Binary format NaNs are represented with **the exponential field filled with ones** (like infinity values), and some **non-zero number in the significand** (to make them distinct from infinity values). The original IEEE 754 standard from 1985 (IEEE 754-1985) only described binary floating-point formats, and did not specify how the signaled/quiet state was to be tagged. In practice, the most significant bit of the significand determined whether a NaN is signalling or quiet. Two different implementations, with reversed meanings, resulted.

*Source:* [NaN Encoding (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Encoding)

The article also goes on to note that in 2008, the IEEE 754-2008 revision adds a suggested method for indicating if the NaN should be quiet or verbose.

> NaN is identified by having the top five bits of the combination field after the sign bit set to ones. The sixth bit of the field is the 'is_quiet' flag. The standard follows the interpretation as an 'is_signaling' flag. I.e. the signaled/quiet bit is zero if the NaN is quiet, and non-zero if the N is identified by having the aN is signaling.

Basically, as before, the exponent is all ones, and the last bit indicates whether it is quiet or not.

My interpretation is that a NaN could be represented in a number of ways, including as follows:

```
0 11111111 00000000000000000000010
```

Comment: A couple of inaccuracies: division of a nonzero finite number by zero will give a suitably-signed infinity (not a NaN) under default exception handling. And the second paragraph you quote relates to the decimal32 format rather than the binary32 format that the OP is using. (It's only the decimal floating-point formats that have the "combination field" that combines exponent and significand information.)

Comment: Thanks @MarkDickinson , you're completely correct. Revised my answer.