# Unequal output values from Python and Julia

Tags: python, syntax, julia

I am implementing the Mandelbrot function both in Python and Julia; however, after the 6th iteration, the codes yield different results. What can be the main reason?

Here is the code in Python:

```
def mandelbrot(a):
    z = 0
    for i in range(50):
        z = z**2 + a
    return z
```

and, here is the same code in Julia:

```
function mandelbrot(a)
    z = 0
    for i=1:50
        z = z^2 + a
    end
    return z
end
```

Comment: Could you add an example of the ways in which the result is different? Absent other information, slightly different floating point rounding would be my first guess.

Comment: You could try the julia code with z initialized to big"0.0" and see if the results change.

Comment: Starting with 0.1, I get the exact same sequence.

Comment: what `different results`? You should show these results. Don't expect that we will run code to see it.

Comment: It is likely integer overflow. Do they differ if a is a float?

Answer (score 6):

This does not seem to be reproducible for points within the Mandelbrot set:

```py
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def mandelbrot(a):
...     z = 0
...     for i in range(50):
...         z = z**2 + a
...     return z
...
>>> mandelbrot(-0.75)
-0.40274177046812404
>>> mandelbrot(0.1)
0.11270166537925831
>>> mandelbrot(0.2)
0.2763932022500072
```

```
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.6.1 (2021-04-23)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> function mandelbrot(a)
           z = 0
           for i=1:50
               z = z^2 + a
           end
           return z
       end
mandelbrot (generic function with 1 method)

julia> mandelbrot(-0.75)
-0.40274177046812404

julia> mandelbrot(0.1)
0.11270166537925831

julia> mandelbrot(0.2)
0.2763932022500072
```

The only difference I have been able to observe thus far is that for points *outside* the set, Python may return an OverflowError where Julia returns `Inf`.

```py
>>> mandelbrot(0.3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in mandelbrot
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

```
julia> mandelbrot(0.3)
Inf
```

presumably due to the two languages making somewhat different decisions as regards handling floating point special values such as `Inf`.

In particular, Python by default does not appear to follow the standard rules for IEEE 754 floating point arithmetic, wherein the following should return `+` and `-` `Inf`, respectively (c.f. [IEEE 754, division by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678698/ieee-754-division-by-zero))

```
>>> 1.0/+0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
>>> 1.0/-0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

whereas Julia does:

```
julia> 1.0/+0.0
Inf
julia> 1.0/-0.0
-Inf
```